# JBoss SSO Cache

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, jboss, ldap, single-sign-on

We have successfully configured SSO in a JBoss EAP 6.3 cluster with two nodes.

The thing is, i don't understand the relation between the replicated cache named "sso" that we had to create, and the cache-type (set to default) in our security domain (the domain connects with an ldap).

The security domain uses that replicated cache? which cache uses? Because we want to configure a timeout for the cache, so if something changes on ldap, the cache refreshes.

A common example of this scenario is when the user gets new permissions, then he wants to access the new functionalities immediately or in a short period of time. Actually we have to restart the whole JBoss, and thats not good at all.

Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="true" >OUR_DOMAIN</security-domain>
```

With that line on the **jboss-web.xml**, we get the behaviour that we were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In the cluster mode, the **SSO** cache is used to authenticate a user on one node (the authentication occurs in a security domain) and authentication automatically carried across to other nodes in the cluster.

The Security domain cache it is to speed up authentication checks, this can be shared between nodes with a replicated cache. But the existence of credentials in the cache doesn't warrant that this authenticated in the application.

For example, if you It sets to true the attribute `reauthenticate` of `sso`, this attribute is a flag to determine whether each request needs to be reauthenticated to the securityRealm. Setting to true can allow web applications with different security-domain configurations to share an **SSO**.

I hope this help.

Comment: We already got the reauthenticate attribute setted to true. The thing is that when the user logs in, it didnt refresh the roles from ldap. Instead of that is getting the roles from some sort of cache. To test that scenario we changed a role assigned for a specified user, and with that same user we logout, and then login, but nothing changes.

Comment: @Mateo Try enable trace level for the category `org.jboss.security.auth.spi` and `org.jboss.as.web.sso`, and verifies this by performing the user login again and that is not taking from JAAS cache